# no applicable method for 'separate_' applied to an object of class "character" >

Tags: r, backend

I have a dataframe composed by one column which I want to split into more columns using the separator ";". Here's what I got so far:

```
Datos_UNMDP <- read.csv("Registros.csv", header = T, sep = "$")
library(tidyverse)
library(bibliometrix)
AU <- Datos_UNMDP$AU 
AU <- as.data.frame(AU)
```

The dataframe 'AU' is the one i wanna split. I tried using the separate command, like this:

`AU <- separate(data = "AU", col = 1, into = NA, sep = ";", remove = F, convert = F, extra = "warn", fill = "warn")`

But when I execute it I receive the following message:

> Error in UseMethod("separate_") :
> no applicable method for 'separate_' applied to an object of class "character"

I already executed the class() command to make sure I'm working on a dataframe object, so I'm not sure where is the error. I'm pretty new in R so I have several doubts on the code I'm doing.

Comment: Try `data=AU`, not `data="AU"`.In your current code, you're not `separate`ing your data.frame `AU`, but the character string`"AU"`.

Comment: Ok, so I did it like you say and now I receive the following error: `Error: `into` must be a character vector`. I put an `NA` value because i'm not sure how many columns my data frame will have once I split the column. Maybe I should put a high number in `into` and try to remove the NA columns later?

Comment: From the online doc for `tidyr::separate`: "into Names of new variables to create as character vector. Use NA to omit the variable in the output".  `into` has no default and you're not providing a value.

Comment: Right, I understand now that i have to declare a character vector in `into` in order to generate new columns. The thing is, I don't know how many columns I will need in the output, because i'm working with a csv with values delimited with semicolon. Do I have a way to know how many semicolons does each row have?

Comment: Please read the online documentation.  `extra` and `fill` define how `separate` will be have.  As you haven't provided and sample data, you have to figure out for yourself what the appropriate settings might be.  You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimum reproducible example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.